# How to set the TXT records from Namecheap to Digital Ocean?

Tags: dns, digital-ocean

I have bought a domain from NameCheap and bought host from Digital Ocean. I have set all other records as specified on NameCheap, but I am unable to enter the TXT records (Simply because it is not letting me.)

This is how my TXT records that I am supposed to enter look like on NameCheap (I'm gonna add dummy data): t=sqf3 include:sqf.myemail.com ~all

The two fields available on Digital Ocean are: 
Enter name: 
Enter text:

now, how do I enter this?

Please let me know, guys.

Thanks!

Comment: when you say it is not letting you, are you getting any errors? (though this may be better raising with their customer support, it could be a problem at their end.

Comment: It's showing an error, saying I cannot add special characters. 

I wrote out the TXT records.. What do I enter in which field? Let me know. @MichaelB

Comment: Well that is a valid record, you could try removing the tilde ~ character, just to see if that is what is causing the problem (A tilde in an SPF record means it will soft fail, meaning it will still make it to your inbox, but be marked in the headers) - unfortunately it definitely sounds like a support issue.